# Saving external dependencies to projects repository

Tags: bazel

"(new_)git_repository" and "(new_)http_archive" workspace rules deal with external projects in such way that any external dependency is copied to temporary directory linked to workspace as `${WORKSPACE}/bazel-workspace/external/${EXTERNAL_DEP_NAME}` on build or prefetch.

I'd like to save external dependencies locally in my repo, so if remote repository vanishes i'd have copy of dependency even on a new machine, where it wasn't cached.

Can I somehow change default behaviour without writing custom workspace rule?

Answer (score 3):

Bazel does have a flag you could use for this: `--experimental_repository_cache`.  It is designed to be a system-wide cache so that multiple projects on one machine don't have to re-download dependencies, but you could use it per-repository.  Basically you'd say:

```
bazel build --experimental_repository_cache=$PWD/my_cache //foo
```

Then all external repositories would be downloaded to the `my_cache` directory in your project.

This *is* a cache keyed by the hash of your external dependencies' content, so it's not going to be very human-readable, but it would let you  keep your external dependencies in your VCS fairly easily.

(Theoretically you could even check in a `.bazelrc` file to specify this option by default, but `--experimental_repository_cache` only takes an absolute path right now, so it's a bit impractical.  I filed [a bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3516) to handle the relative path use case.)

Comment: So if I update library hash in path will change, and diff in repo will become "delete old version of library and add new version"?

Comment: No, the cache will just add a new entry (since it doesn't know if another project is still using that archive).  You'd have to clean up old entries manually (definitely a downside!).

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it sounds like you want to just check it in the VCS. If we're talking about an http archive then download it manually, stick it under the relevant "third_party" sub folder with the BUILD file you craft for it and you're done.

If you want to use Bazel mechanisms to download and check-in the external dependencies then this isn't currently supported.
Maybe you should open an [issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues)

Comment: Yes, I want to check them into VCS, but i want to use bazel mechanisms to download/update them.

Comment: I see. Not sure this is supported and I don't think custom workspace rule will help you either. I'd suggest changing the question a bit to focus on how to use bazel mechanisms to manage **checked-in** external dependencies

Comment: Ittai is right, right now bazel doesn't support automatically updating external repositories.